# Travis CI: Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly

Tags: java, travis-ci

After [my commit](https://github.com/k-tamura/easybuggy/commit/a66dae3bb5ed40b2a315cc739c335972990105e7) as follows,

```
- <a href="admins/main?logintype=openredirect"><fmt:message
+ <a href="admins/main?logintype=openredirect&goto=/uid/serverinfo.jsp"><fmt:message
```

Travis CI has started to fail to build my application with the following log:

```
$ export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH
$ java -Xmx32m -version
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)
$ javac -J-Xmx32m -version
javac 1.8.0_131
$ true

$ mvn -DskipTests=true clean verify
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java


The command "mvn -DskipTests=true clean verify" exited with 1.

Done. Your build exited with 1.
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to fix?

For more detail: https://travis-ci.org/k-tamura/easybuggy/jobs/271565768

.travis.yml

```
language: java

jdk:
  - openjdk7
  - oraclejdk7

install: true

script: mvn -DskipTests=true clean verify

notifications:
  email:
- ktamura.biz.80@gmail.com
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The owner of the travis-ci repository on GitHub claims they can no longer support `oraclejdk7`.

https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/7884#issuecomment-308451879

You should use `oraclejdk8`.